# How to get JACK / jackd not to run at startup

Tags: startup, jack

I installed JACK and qjackctl on Ubuntu 20.04. Now jackd starts on startup, which means that my normal (non-DAW) applications can't produce sound until I run `sudo killall jackd`.

There's no sign of JACK or jackd in the Ubuntu startup applications, nor in `sudo service --status-all`, nor in `sudo systemctl list-unit-files`, nor `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`, nor `ls /etc/init.d/`.

I think that's actually all of the Ubuntu software startup mechanisms I'm aware of, so this is a great learning opportunity for me: how on earth is this daemon starting itself? And how can I disable it?

EDIT: Found this in `/var/log/syslog`: https://pastebin.com/ApsMfvUd . Maybe this has to do with pulseaudio configuration?

Comment: Did you add any of your DAW-applications which rely on jackd to your startup-applications?

Comment: Good thought! The only one is Bitwig Studio, and `bitwig` doesn't appear in any of the areas I listed above. But I do notice `pulseaudio-enable-autospawn` enabled in `sudo systemctl list-unit-files`? Not sure if that is related?

Comment: No, that's not related, it just ensures that pulseaudio will be started. The problem is , while using jackd, pulseaudio is not connected to alsa (since jackd is). jackd should not be started at login at all unless an application in autostart is starting jackd via dbus. Did you look in `~/.config/autostart`?

Comment: I hadn't! There's no JACK or Bitwig, but there is `mpd.desktop`, which may be related?

Comment: That could be related, you should try to temporary remove `mpd.desktop` from `~/.config/autostart` and check if the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had modified the PulseAudio configuration `/etc/pulse/default.pa` with the lines

```
load-module module-jack-sink
load-module module-jack-source
```

This was causing PulseAudio, which starts at startup, to try to start JACK at startup.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Just read your log and saw it too. Also consider to [enable realtime permissions for jack](https://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html). A nice way to configure jack is `studio-controls`, with default config it will manage the connections to run pulse and jack together and remember the state of jack (running or not) surviving reboots, that's pretty cool. I really prefer `studio-controls` over `qjackctl`, no need to write startup-scripts to run jack together with pulseaudio.

Comment: Nice, thanks so much for all your help through debugging this!